# I am very new to velocity apache script

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Present code is am using is like this:

```
#set($startdate=$datetool.format("yyyymmdd",$fromDate))

#set($enddate=$datetool.format("yyyymmdd",$endDate))
```

But I dont know how to continue.
I want to find out difference between two dates which are in the format `yyyymmdd`, and if the difference is greater than one month, I have to divide that into months, so please anyone help to solve this.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you tried, and an example of the expected result?

Comment: #set( $inter = $pageParameters.wiEndDate.compareTo($pageParameters.wiStartDate))\\

Comment: Can you tell how to add days to already existing days

Comment: Example: I want to add 30 days to end date and i want to get it printed

Comment: I am trying this #set( $pageParameters.wiEndDate = ($pageParameters.wiStartDate+ 30))\\ but it snot working

Comment: @anuraghn your way it will not work . You can send `LocalDate` or `Calendar` to add days

Comment: @Igoranze  Can you show how? Since am new to it am not getting that even i dont know java.. Can you help me to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would suggest you to to use [ComparisonDateTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html) in Velocity to get date difference

```
 $dateComparisonTool.difference($startdate,$enddate).days
```

Comment: Can you tell how to add days to already existing days.Example: I want to add 30 days to end date and i want to get it printed.I am trying this #set( $pageParameters.wiEndDate = ($pageParameters.wiStartDate+ 30))\\ but it snot working

Comment: Can you add your code in question so that easy for me too sorted this out

Comment: It didn't work for me. I got 1 as answer all the time. Regardless what the enddate was set to.

Comment: #set( $inter = $pageParameters.wiEndDate.compareTo($pageParameters.wiStartDate))Difference is : $inter\\ This code I am using to get difference but am getting answer as 0ne for any dates

Comment: #set( $endDate = $webapi.parseInt($fromDate) + '30')\\
New enddate is : $endDate\\  This code am using to 30 days to start date even this is not working